# Weird error when trying to use training data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

When trying to run the following code (I've replaced my data with 1,2,3... numbers so as to make the problem reproducible)

```
x_train = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]*1000).astype("float32")
y_train = np.asarray([1.0]*1000).astype("float32")
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError,
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    metrics=['mae'],
)
model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train,epochs=5)
```

I get `TypeError: Expected float32 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Equal', got 'auto' of type 'str' instead. Error: Expected float32, got 'auto' of type 'str' instead.` thrown from the last line.

The error message is kind of meaningless, because there are no strings, so my questions are:

1. What's going on?
2. How to get over this and fit `x_train`,`y_train` specified in the code in the model?

Comment: you are not passing the loss correctly, MeanSquaredError is a class and you should create an instance of it ( as loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())

Comment: @ Dr. Snoppy, Yes! I think you're right. I can train with your suggest. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to instantiate your loss :)

```
tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError() # put parentheses
```